# Converting a react redux block to react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to react native,I have a block of code for a form in react, need to convert this into react native elements using the same let variable AddTodo

```
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
let input

 return (
<div>
  <form onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!input.value.trim()) {
      return
    }
    dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
    input.value = ''
  }}>
    <input ref={node => {
      input = node
    }} />
    <button type="submit">
      Add Todo
    </button>
  </form>
  </div>
 )
 }
 AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)
```

Can anyone help me here? This is the [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-with-undo/src/containers/AddTodo.js)

Comment: Uhm. Replace all your `HTML`-tags with React Native ones, pretty much. Apart from that nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code for react-native, that convert from your react code.
You can find more about react-native [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/getting-started.html).

in html we use  for group other element so for react-native using

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class AddTodo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todoText: ''
    };
  }
 render() {
   return (
     <View>
       <TextInput
         onChangeText={(todoText) => this.setState({todoText})}
         value={this.state.todoText}
       />
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
         if(this.state.todoText) {
           this.props.addTodo(input.value);
            this.setState({ todoText: '' })
         }
       }}>
         <Text>Add Todo</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
   );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addTodo: bindActionCreators(addTodo, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo);
```

You can find react-native redux todo example [here](http://blog.thebakery.io/todomvc-with-react-native-and-redux/)

Comment: Thanks @bun houth .Can you specify where I should create the constructor and initialize the state  todoText in this example https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-with-undo/src/containers/AddTodo.js